# Auto populated infopath form based on current user

Tags: infopath

I have 2 questions

1. Is there a way to auto populate a infopath based on current user. (i.e. Title, First name, last name, address, city, tx, zip, email address, phone number)
2. Is there a way to auto populate cascaded fields? For example, if user select Los Angeles  from the Account drop down, then I would like to auto populate Region field with West and also auto populate RegionManager?

Please suggest or if you know a good link for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can auto populate all the user information by using getuserprofilebyname web service.
have a look here to get a better understanding of how to use. http://claytoncobb.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/userprofileservice-extended/

Coming to your second question, you can make use of a lists.

Example--Account info will be a list with account, region and Region manager column.

Account dropdown will pull data from list.
You can write rules to get value of Region and manager textbox filtering the value in the account dropdown.